# How do I convert x, y coordinates from one graph with a small scale to a new matplotlib graph of a much greater size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am using tkinter to manually draw lines on a canvas then record the x, y coordinates. I'd like to convert those x,y coordinates to a very differently scaled canvas and plot them using matplotlib. My tkinter canvas currently is sized 690(x) x 490(y). I'd like to convert those coordinates to a graph with the dimensions of x(ranging from -5300 to 5300) and y(ranging from -3650 to 3650) with zero being the center of the graph. How do I do that range/scale conversion? Thanks!

Current tkinter canvas coordinate range:

```
root = tk.Tk()
background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file="Pitch2.png")
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", width=690, height=560)
```

Desired matplotlib range:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.ylim(-3650, 3650)
plt.xlim(-5300, 5300)
filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Pitch.png')
im = plt.imread(filename)
graph_2, = ax.plot([], marker='.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 7,300 pixels across your `matplotlib` plot, i.e. [-3650,3650]. There are 690 across your `Tk` image.

So multiply your `Tk` x-coordinate by `7300/690` and add the result to -3650 to get the `matplotlib` x-coordinate:

```
mpltx = (Tkx * 7300/690) - 3650 

mplty = (Tky * 10600/560) - 5300
```

Remember y-coordinate comes **before** x-coordinate in Numpy.